# Refresh en fecha actual fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar, flask

Estoy trabajando con full calendar pero tengo un  problema, mi calendario tiene datos desde 2016, y se requiere hacer cambio de varios de los eventos, implemente el evento de editar, todo bien, pero el problema es que cuando guardo un dato y estoy en el 2016, se refresca la página y me redirige de nuevo al 2017 (día actual) y quiero evitar eso.  he intentado creando un boton y colocando la funcion

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

Pero debido a que cuando doy save Changes en la  siguiente ventana modal siguiente, se actualiza, no puedo corroborar si en realidad sirve el botón, pero al parecer si sirve, porque en la consola me marca que vuelve a obtener los datos de los eventos. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por motivo de la función de python flask que estoy utilizando, me manda un render_template que actualiza la página nuevamente, y es parte de lo que quiero corregir.

Función de python :

```
@app.route('/calendar', methods=['GET','POST'])
def calendar():


      #####################

           "Lógica"

      ####################       

    sql="Consulta"

    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,sql)

    return render_template('calendar.html'); ##Aqui renderiza nuevamente la página
```

y aqui dejó el código de fullcalendar que estoy utilizando :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        customButtons: {

            refreshBtn: {
                themeIcon: "refresh",
                text: "Refresh",
                click: function () {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

                }
            }
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prevYear,nextYear,today, refreshBtn',
            center: 'title,prev,next',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        weekNumbers: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: {
            url: 'datacalendar',
            error: function () {
                console.log("error")
            }
        },

        eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            //alert("nombre del evento" + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") );
            //$('#myModalLabel').html(event.title);
            $('#ModalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#start').val(event.start.format("YYYY-DD-MM  hh:mm:ss"));
            $('#end').val(event.end.format("YYYY-DD-MM  hh:mm:ss"));
            $('#category').val(event.title);
            $('#Modalevent').modal('show');


        },
        select: function (start, end) {

            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },



    });

});
```

¿alguien podría ayudarme a resolver esto? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Justo ando jugando con FullCalendar, en un Callback en el JavaScript dale lo siguiente:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(2016, 11));
```

Comment: Lo siento, soy un poco nuevo con fullcalendar, pero a lo que te refieres es a que bedo crear un nuevo callback y colocarle ese javascript?

Comment: yo también :D en algún lado debes mandarle el mes y el año, en caso no uses un CallBack de JavaScript, esa línea de código escríbela luego de   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... }); //Aquí

Comment: Podrías tener un par de hidden fields que guarden el año y el mes, eso lo envías en tu request al server y cuando haga se visualice, ese 2016 y ese 11 serán definidos por tus variables, acto seguido, podrás ver el dónde estuviste antes de guardar los cambios, ¿Me dejo entender hermano?

Comment: si, ya logro comprender mejor, los hidden fields los debo colocar en el formulario de los cambios ¿no es asi?.

Comment: ya los he agregado dentro del formulario, cree un botón en fullcalendar llamada refresh, al cual dentro de su callback le pase lo que me dijiste y agregue otros, y tengo lo siguiente ahora : refreshBtn: {
                 themeIcon: "refresh",
                 text: "Refresh",
                 click: function () {
                     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        var actual = $('#calendar-place').fullCalendar('getDate');
                        $('#calendar-place').fullCalendar('gotoDate', actual);
                 }
             }
         }

Comment: Pero no sé como debe de ser el proceso para obtener los datos de mes y dia, sé que en el calback solo puedo dar el valor a estos con algo así :  $('#start').val("valor")), pero no sé como sería el proceso completo para que cuando le de refresh el server mande los campos y refresque en la fecha indicada.

Comment: @Roger Por curiosidad hermano ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: no hermano, no pude.